# Bar Chart Not Rendering As Intended in d3.JS

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I started visualizing data I had extracted using pandas. I've checked out the d3.js tutorials and examples and decided to write a simple bar chart, but what is rendering is not in accordance to the data i have in csv format. The label on the y-axis doesn't appear,neither does the data appear on the y-axis. One of the fields on the x-axis doesn't even have data visualizing.

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
// Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 50
  },
  width = canvas.width - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = canvas.height - margin.top - margin.bottom;


var x = d3.scaleBand()
  .rangeRound([0, width])
  .padding(0.1);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .rangeRound([height, 0]);

context.translate(margin.left, margin.top);

d3.csv("data/ecci.csv", function(data) {
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.NGNAmountCashBalance = +d.NGNAmountCashBalance;
    d.Region = d.Region;
  });
  console.log(data[5]);
  x.domain(data.map(function(d) {
    return d.Region;
  }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return d.NGNAmountCashBalance;
  })]);

  context.beginPath();
  x.domain().forEach(function(d) {
    context.moveTo(x(d) + x.bandwidth() / 2, height);
    context.lineTo(x(d) + x.bandwidth() / 2, height + 6);
  });

  context.strokeStyle = "black";
  context.stroke();

  context.textAlign = "center";
  context.textBaseline = "top";
  x.domain().forEach(function(d) {
    context.fillText(d, x(d) + x.bandwidth() / 2, height + 6);
  });

  context.beginPath();

  context.strokeStyle = "black";
  context.stroke();

  context.textAlign = "right";
  context.textBaseline = "middle";

  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(-6.5, 0 + 0.5);
  context.lineTo(0.5, 0 + 0.5);
  context.lineTo(0.5, height + 0.5);
  context.lineTo(-6.5, height + 0.5);
  context.strokeStyle = "black";
  context.stroke();

  context.save();
  context.rotate(-Math.PI / 2);
  context.textAlign = "right";
  context.textBaseline = "top";
  context.font = "light 13px verdana";
  context.fillText("ACCIS Chart", -10, 10);
  context.restore();

  context.fillStyle = "steelblue";
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    context.fillRect(x(d.Region), y(d.NGNAmountCashBalance), x.bandwidth(), height - y(d.NGNAmountCashBalance));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.5/d3.min.js"></script>
<canvas width="660" height="500"></canvas>
```

JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/gbade/o11d5tb8/

Please, what exactly am I missing?

Comment: Can you please provide a complete, functional example?

Comment: @elias, http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/8952219

Answer (score 2):

It's tough to answer this **without** seeing your data but assuming it looks something like this (at a minimum):

```
NGNAmountCashBalance,Region
10,One
20,Two
30,Three
40,Four
```

Your chart works for me **except** for this part:

> neither does the data appear on the y-axis

And that's because you haven't drawn the y-axis.  Since you are working with `canvas`, it would look something like:

```
  var yTickCount = 5,
      yTicks = y.ticks(yTickCount);

  context.beginPath();
  yTicks.forEach(function(d) {
    context.moveTo(0, y(d) + 0.5);
    context.lineTo(-6, y(d) + 0.5);
  });
  context.strokeStyle = "black";
  context.stroke();

  context.textAlign = "right";
  context.textBaseline = "middle";
  yTicks.forEach(function(d) {
    context.fillText(d, -9, y(d));
  });
```

Here's a full [running example](http://plnkr.co/edit/k0QCe6DJD9lm3Ss98Deq?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks Mark, I was able to get values on the y-axis rendering, but values for a field on the x-xis is not rendering.

Comment: This is part of my csv:

NGNAmountCashBalance Region
160000 Africa
300000 Africa
300000 Africa
300000 Africa

Comment: @gbade_, does your file really look like that?  I don't see any commas, which is odd for a `csv`...

Comment: I'm sorry, it has comas. stackoverflow has limits and I wish I could upload the CSV here. But data for Africa are not being represented.

Comment: @gbade_, does Africa really repeat like that?  You are using a `scaleBand` and from the [docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#band_domain) `stringified version of the domain value uniquely identifies the corresponding band.`  They must be unique!  What do the different "Africas" mean?

Comment: I just created a new plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/eYk9u8?p=preview. My csv is present there.

Comment: i'm currently a noob to all things d3.JS. The docs are a bit all over the place, and i'm learning what I can from examples.

Comment: @gbade_, you've got two problems.  First, what are you going to do about all that repeating data?  If you are only showing one value per region, do you want to show the min, max, average?  Right now the chart is only showing the last value.  Second, the reason you don't see Africa is because the last value in the csv is 2000.  Your chart max though is 4.5 **billion**.  Africa is simply too small to see.

Comment: I want to show the max value per region (that'd be the summation of values per region, no?).